# Spring Batch ChunkRequest throws stackOverflow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-integration, jackson-databind, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am struggling with **Spring Batch RemoteChunking** with newer versions of Spring boot.
First i try to send ChunkRequest as event, it wasn't possible because it has no public default constructor. As solution I had to create a custom serializer and Deserializer and I set them in my application.properties correctly.
After doing all of that, now i am having Stackoverflow. (i understand the reason just by checking the ChunkRequest class which Has Collection of stepExecutions and the step execution have jobExecution which have stepExecutions)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/integration/chunk/ChunkRequest.html

What i am missing, even after serializing ChunkRequest as byte[]?

```
    2022-05-14 00:22:31.880  INFO 11974 --- [container-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-anonymous.3ac5789f-01ba-493f-a7ce-6f6f4429a0a1-2, groupId=anonymous.3ac5789f-01ba-493f-a7ce-6f6f4429a0a1] (Re-)joining group
    2022-05-14 00:22:31.891  INFO 11974 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=client-job]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]
    2022-05-14 00:22:31.901  INFO 11974 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [dispatchStep]
    2022-05-14 00:22:31.948 ERROR 11974 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step dispatchStep in job client-job
    
    org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Retry exhausted after last attempt in recovery path, but exception is not skippable.; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'clientRequests'; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util
    .Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]), failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=ChunkRequest: jobId=1, sequence=0, contribution=[StepContribution: read=0, written=0, filtered=0, readSkips=0, writeSkips=0, processSkips=0, exitStatus=EXECUTING], item count=1, headers={id=ae9dbd76-ed32-0410-dacd-b6c700de87b2, contentType=application/json, timestamp=1652484151911}]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor$5.recover(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:429) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.handleRetryExhausted(RetryTemplate.java:539) ~[spring-retry-1.3.3.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:387) ~[spring-retry-1.3.3.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:255) ~[spring-retry-1.3.3.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.BatchRetryTemplate.execute(BatchRetryTemplate.java:217) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.write(FaultTolerantChunkProcessor.java:444) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:217) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:152) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:413) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:320) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.5.jar:4.3.5]
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:768) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:310) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
        at pt.bayonne.sensei.importclients.ImportClientsApplication.main(ImportClientsApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: failed to send Message to channel 'clientRequests'; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList[0]->org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution["jobExecution"]->org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution["stepExecutions"]->java.util
```

Any Idea? Any example of the sample of application using RemoteChunking? Thanks

After adding this:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1488

```
I got a new exception:
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7B0A2020
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:963) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:397) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Why cannot you use a plain Java serialization? Why trying to deal with JSON when that `ChunkRequest` is not JSON compatible according to its internals?

Comment: Hey, @ArtemBilan thanks for your reply. As you can see from my question, I've tried to implement my own custom serializer and deserializer but for some reason, spring batch/integration was picking the Jackson one. I've set it properly in the application.properties but anyways it was taking the Jackson and explode with stackoverflow error

Answer (score 2):

> i understand the reason just by checking the ChunkRequest class which Has Collection of stepExecutions and the step execution have jobExecution which have stepExecutions

You nailed it, and in the end you are hitting https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1488. This is a  Jackson issue, because other serialization mechanisms are able to serialize/deserialize `ChunkRequest` objects.

Comment: Hey @Mahmoud Ben Hassine, as always thanks for your reply. I'll take a look.

Comment: Using the approach i get this error:                                                                      
 Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 7B0A2020
 at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:963) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:397) ~[na:na]
 at org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils.deserialize(SerializationUtils.java:81) ~[spring-core-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
 ... 27 common frames omitted. @Mahmoud Ben Hassine

Answer (score 1):

As @Mahmoud Ben Hassine mentioned,

> This is a Jackson issue because other serialization mechanisms are
> able to serialize/deserialize ChunkRequest objects.

Once you create your custom serializer, for example:

```
package pt.bayonne.sensei.RemoteChunking.job.serde;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.chunk.ChunkRequest;
import org.springframework.util.SerializationUtils;
import pt.bayonne.sensei.RemoteChunking.dto.ClientDTO;

public class ChunkRequestSerializer implements Serializer<ChunkRequest>{

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChunkRequestSerializer.class);

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, ChunkRequest data) {

        if (data == null) {
            return null;
        }

        String dataType = data.getClass().getName();
        logger.debug("--> serializing: {}",dataType);

        byte[] dataBytes = null;
        try {


            dataBytes = SerializationUtils.serialize(data);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error serializing data", e);
        }
        
        return dataBytes;
    }

}
```

You have to specify that it is using the native encoding.

```
#produces
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.clientRequests.destination=clientRequests
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.clientRequests.producer.use-native-encoding=true
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=pt.bayonne.sensei.RemoteChunking.job.serde.ChunkRequestSerializer
```

Otherwise you will have more exceptions and sometimes it will continue picking the default framework serializer/deserializer. Using the Mixins doesn't help that much